# multiple HTML5 audio behavior : one track at a time please

Tags: jquery, html, audio

First I suppose Ill show you what I have so far....

http://jsfiddle.net/fDRnY/

I have multiple `<audio>` tags in my html structure. Im using a standard technique to play the files with an `<a>` tag

```
$('.play').on('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var song = $(this).next('audio').get(0);

    if(song.paused){
        song.play();

    }else {
        song.pause();    
    }
});
```

Next I wrote a simple function to play the following track when the currently playing track has ended...

```
$('audio').on('ended',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var $next = $(this).nextAll().eq(1).get(0);

        if($next.paused){
            $next.play();
        }
});
```

Then there are a few more functions for the visual UI adding a highlight class to the currently playing track...

```
$('audio').on('playing',function(){
    $(this).prev().addClass('highlight')
});

$('audio').on('ended',function(){
    $(this).prev().removeClass('highlight')
});

 $('audio').on('pause',function(){ 
    $(this).prev().removeClass('highlight') 
 });
```

Now my problem: If you click more than one track they will play simultaneously. I want any track that is currently playing to pause when you click another one.

I found similar posts with similar concerns on Stack and I have found this function which loops through all `audio` objects and pauses them...

```
var allAudioEls = $('audio');

function pauseAllAudio() {
   allAudioEls.each(function() {
      var a = $(this).get(0);
      a.pause();
   });
}
```

If I call the function like this (on line 3 below)...

```
$('.play').on('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
pauseAllAudio();        
var song = $(this).next('audio').get(0);

    if(song.paused){
        song.play();

    }else {
        song.pause();    
    }
});
```

It almost works,it pauses the other track that is playing and plays the one most recently clicked, but now you cant pause the track thats currently playing anymore. I hope that makes sense. Im pretty sure its some kind of flow issue, but I am a total beginner... Maybe I need
a whole new technique to do this. I think Im on the right track with looping through the `audio` objects... any help would be appreciated, and like I said Im a newbie. Any detailed explanations would be even more appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Im self taught and I love Stack as a resource. If you feel you should vote this question down, please tell me why. I really want to learn jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a parameter to your `pauseAllAudio` function which excludes a particular element:

```
function pauseAllAudio(exclude) {
    allAudioEls.each(function() {
        var a = $(this).get(0);
        if(a !== exclude) {
            a.pause();
        }
    }
}
```

And then pass `song` to `pauseAllAudio`:

```
var song = $(this).next('audio').get(0);
pauseAllAudio(song);
```

If you didn't need to play the song in this code block, you could simply move the `pauseAllAudio()` call down beneath the check. However, doing so would make it unable to ever play for longer than the infinitesimally small amount of time it would take to go from `song.play()` to `pauseAllAudio()`

Comment: this works exactly as I wanted! thanks so much! I have to admit I don't exactly understand what's happening with the exclude parameter... if you could tell me which concepts to research to better understand id feel much better about using this. again, much gratitude. Thanks.

Comment: The `exclude` parameter is a [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science)) (think memory address or C/C++ pointer) to a particular DOM object, as is the variable `a`. The if statement checks to see if the references are equal. If they are, then they are the same DOM object and we exclude it from being paused.